# Resizing multiple images in a folder with different format

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I am currently using pil to resize multiple images in a folder that contains several images in different format such as **bmp, jpg and tif**.

I have successfully implemented the following codes to resize the images of bmp and jpg but I failed to do it for **tif images**.

```
import shutil
import os
from PIL import Image

dir_name = "C:/Users/fyp/test1/"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)
destDirectory = "C:/Users/fyp/test2/"

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".tif"):
        img = Image.open(dir_name + item)
        imgResize = img.resize((224, 224), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        imgResize.save(destDirectory + item[:-4] + '.tif', quality = 95)
```

An error appeared in tif images that is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-b666efd7a46f> in <module>
     10     if item.endswith(".tif"):
     11         img = Image.open(dir_name + item)
---> 12         imgResize = img.resize((224, 224), Image.ANTIALIAS)
     13         imgResize.save(destDirectory + item[:-4] + '.tif', quality = 95)
     14 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in resize(self, size, resample, box, reducing_gap)
   1852 
   1853         if self.mode in ["LA", "RGBA"]:
-> 1854             im = self.convert(self.mode[:-1] + "a")
   1855             im = im.resize(size, resample, box)
   1856             return im.convert(self.mode)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in convert(self, mode, matrix, dither, palette, colors)
    871         """
    872 
--> 873         self.load()
    874 
    875         if not mode and self.mode == "P":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py in load(self)
   1068     def load(self):
   1069         if self.use_load_libtiff:
-> 1070             return self._load_libtiff()
   1071         return super().load()
   1072 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py in _load_libtiff(self)
   1180 
   1181         if err < 0:
-> 1182             raise OSError(err)
   1183 
   1184         return Image.Image.load(self)

OSError: -2
```

May I know the reason for this? Thank you very much!

**UPDATE 1/8/2021**

I guess I find out the solution to this issue. The main problem that caused this error maybe due to some images are being concurrently used and python may not be able to execute the function on manipulating the images. I restart my PC and the problem is resolved. Thank you very much for all the answers below. Feel free to comment more for any other possible solutions or reasons!

Comment: Did you try to use the endig `.tiff` with two *f*s? Maybe it has to do with that. It seems like PIL expects this.

Comment: Tiff files can contain many sub images. Can you share the tiff file that it causes the error?

Comment: @TheMultiplexer I have tried with **.tiff** but it still does not work :(

Comment: @İsmailDurmaz      I checked my tiff images do not contain any sub images within it but I am stucked with the reason why the above codes output such an OSError.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mystic error. And I couldn't find any clue the reason. If the library is not important, you can use `opencv` for image operations. I tested and it was worked for tiff files.

Installation

```
$ pip install opencv-python
or
$ pip3 install opencv-python
```

Source Code

```py
import cv2
import shutil
import os

dir_name = "C:/Users/fyp/test1/"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)
destDirectory = "C:/Users/fyp/test2/"

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".tif"):
        img = cv2.imread(dir_name + item)
        imgResize = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imwrite(destDirectory + item[:-4] + '.tif', imgResize)
```